# Average within-cluster distance using divisive clustering

Tags: clustering, distance, proof

I have to prove that the average within-cluster distance for 10 data points cannot increase when going from 1 cluster to 2 clusters (divisive clustering).

Intuitively, it seems obvious that this is true because each time you allocate a point to the second group, it will have a smaller distance from the centre of that group, so on average it will be closer to the other points in that group than the points in the first group. Otherwise you would keep that point in the first group.

I'm not sure how to formally prove it though. Can anyone offer any guidance?

Thanks

Edit:

So the definition of average distance I was given was this

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{l=1}^k \sum\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq C_l}d(\vec x_i,\vec x_j)}{\pmatrix{{C_1}\\2}+\pmatrix{{C_2}\\2}+...+\pmatrix{{C_k}\\2}}$$

Where $C_i$ is the number of observations in cluster $i$.

Comment: Your formulations are unclear. What is `average within-cluster distance`: are there meant distances between points or between a point and the centroid (the mean)? Also, when there become 2 clusters, what is "average" distance - average of the 2 averages? or what?

Comment: Distances between points. When there are 2 clusters I think it's the average of the 2 averages.

Comment: @ttnphns updated the question to show this